# How to identify multiple errors in JavaScript promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to use promises for the first time but I'm having trouble finding the best way to handle multiple error/exception types.

I'm implementing a user login. It is useful to know on failure if the username doesn't exist or the password is incorrect or if there was some other error.

Below is a portion of my login service which uses AWS Cognito (mostly irrelevant here). In the onFailure callback I have opted for creating my own exceptions. Since my CognitoAuth class implements a Auth interface I don't want to return aws error codes to the client (separation of concerns, hence my own exceptions which could be used by another provider).

```
  public login(loginData: IAuthLoginData): Promise<void> {
    let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: loginData.email,
      Password: loginData.password
    })

    let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: loginData.email,
      Pool: this.userPool
    })

    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: (session: CognitoUserSession, userTrackingConfirmationNecessary: boolean) => {
          resolve()
        },
        onFailure: (err) => {
          switch (err.code) {
            case 'UserNotFoundException':
              reject(new UserNotFoundError())

            case 'UserNotConfirmedException':
              reject(new UserNotConfirmedError())

            case 'NotAuthorizedException':
              reject(new PasswordIncorrectError())

            default:
              reject(new LoginError())
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

The first problem I've come across is the ugliness of TypeScript exceptions, especially when creating numerous ones:

```
export class UserNotFoundError extends Error {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);

    // restore prototype chain
    const actualProto = new.target.prototype;
    if (Object.setPrototypeOf) { Object.setPrototypeOf(this, actualProto); }
    else { this.__proto__ = new.target.prototype; }
  }
}
```

Below is how I handle my promise and exceptions in the client. I am able to identify the reason for the error, but using instance of checks for exceptions seems a bit odd and making me doubt their usefulness here.

```
  private login() {
    this.auth.login({
      email: this.email.value,
      password: this.password.value
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      if (err instanceof UserNotFoundError)
        this.email.setErrors({
          usernotfound: true
        })
      else if (err instanceof UserNotConfirmedError)
        this.form.setErrors({
          usernotconfirmed: true
        })
      else if (err instanceof PasswordIncorrectError)
        this.password.setErrors({
          passwordincorrect: true
        })
      else
        this.form.setErrors({
          ooops: true
        })
    })
  }
```

How should I correctly be identifying the errors that arise in the catch method? Should I be avoiding exceptions as much as possible in TypeScript? I would argue that an enum is better, but I'm really just reinventing my own error system. How do libraries/frameworks handle this?

Ideally I would like as much type safety as possible and I don't really want to **throw** or **reject** strings as that isn't really helpful for the client.